# EXE runs in local Docker container but on Azure

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances

I have an internal application that I would like to run on a bunch of Azure Container Instances. The application requires .Net 4.7.2, as well as an internal SDK. I have managed to get this to run on my local Docker container, but as soon as I push it into an Azure Container Instance, it just...fails. It just says Terminated(reason is failed). There are no logs. With no logs I am at a complete loss. Here is the Dockerfile I am using:

```
# escape=`

ARG REPO=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime
FROM $REPO:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2019

# Install .NET 4.7.2
RUN powershell -Command `
        $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; `
        Invoke-WebRequest `
            -UseBasicParsing `
            -Uri "https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/E/4/6E48E8AB-DC00-419E-9704-06DD46E5F81D/NDP472-KB4054530-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" `
            -OutFile dotnet-framework-installer.exe `
    && start /w .\dotnet-framework-installer.exe /q `
    && del .\dotnet-framework-installer.exe `
    && powershell Remove-Item -Force -Recurse ${Env:TEMP}\*

# Restore the default Windows shell for correct batch processing.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

# Copy all the things
COPY . C:/Build

 # Install Internal SDK
 RUN C:/Build/InternalSDK.Installer.msi /qn

# Copy everything
# COPY . C:\Build

ENTRYPOINT cd C:/Build/build/bin/ && InternalApp.exe -m 18635 -v ./Files -s StratData.strategy -n 10 -l 0 -t 4
```

So, I am new at Docker, but my understanding is that the container is completely ignorant to what is running it, and should behave the same in all environments. Why then does this behave differently when run in a Container Instance?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you try this  https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/blob/master/samples/README.md

Comment: @PankajRawat The sample projects work fine

Comment: Not sure what is the issue but try to use sample project docker file and incorporate your changes on that file.

Comment: .NET Full Framework is probably the worst "customer" for a container. Have a look at Cloud Services instead, it's going to be easier to deploy and debug. Disregard the Internet saying it's deprecated. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-choose-me

Comment: You need to give out the error message so that communities can give your solution.

Comment: @CharlesXu I dont get an error message. I would expect to see it in the "Logs" tab, but all it says in there is "No logs available"

Comment: Do you mind sharing all the things that the Dockerfile needs for the test?